# "card not found" when using "composer network ping --card admin@trial.card"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to deploy my own business network
So I made my own .bna file and card called admin@trail.card
After I importing the card using :

`composer card import --file admin@trial.card`

I run composer card list to verify that the card has been imported

```
$ composer card list

The following Business Network Cards are available:

Connection Profile: hlfv1
┌─────────────────────┬───────────┬──────────────────┐
│ Card Name           │ UserId    │ Business Network │
├─────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────────┤
│ admin@trial         │ admin     │ trial            │
├─────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────────┤
│ PeerAdmin@hlfv1     │ PeerAdmin │                  │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────────┘


Issue composer card list --card <Card Name> to get details a specific card
```

now when I try to ping it I get an error saying that card is not found

```
composer network ping --card admin@trial.card 
Error: Card not found: admin@trial.card
Command failed
```

I also tried using composer-playground
`$composer-playground`
but I get an error popup saying :
`Error: Error trying to ping. Error: No business network has been specified for this connection`

How to solve this issue?

P.S. My fabric environment is running(./startFabric.sh and createPeerAdminCard.sh) I rechecked my docker using `docker ps` and everything is up.

Also, my TransactionLogic.js file is still incomplete so if that's the issue please let me know. (out of 3 transaction function I have finished 1 and want to test it)

It works on https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/ but not on my localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I found where the issue was that the command should have been

`composer network ping --card admin@trial`

rather than

`composer network ping --card admin@trial.card`

I'll keep this post up incase someone makes the same mistake as me.